# Why is my map function returning undefined when used within a promise?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I am fetching a JSON object of key value pairs (date, value) for GDP data.

I want to create an array of just values from the JSON file, but I am getting undefined when using map in the following context:

```js
let dataset;
d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json')
  .then(data => {
  dataset = data.map(each => each[1])
});

console.log(dataset);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```

```
let dataset;
d3.json('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json')
  .then(data => {
  dataset = data.map(each => each[1])
});

console.log(dataset);
```

Sample of the JSON data I am trying to access.

```
{
  "errors": {},
  "id": 120140,
  "source_name": "Federal Reserve Economic Data",
  "source_code": "FRED",
  "code": "GDP",
  "name": "Gross Domestic Product, 1 Decimal",
  "urlize_name": "Gross-Domestic-Product-1-Decimal",
  "display_url": "http://research.stlouisfed.org/fred2/data/GDP.txt",
  "description": "Units: Billions of Dollars\nSeasonal Adjustment: Seasonally Adjusted Annual Rate\nNotes: A Guide to the National Income and Product Accounts of the United States (NIPA) - (http://www.bea.gov/national/pdf/nipaguid.pdf)",
  "updated_at": "2015-12-14T20:00:28.561Z",
  "frequency": "quarterly",
  "from_date": "1947-01-01",
  "to_date": "2015-07-01",
  "column_names": [
    "DATE",
    "VALUE"
  ],
  "private": false,
  "type": null,
  "premium": false,
  "data": [
    [
      "1947-01-01",
      243.1
    ],
    [
      "1947-04-01",
      246.3
    ],
```

Note, I am trying to access data in obj.data in this case, and want to return the second value of each array within the JSON object.

***JSON Source***:https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json

Comment: put the `console.log(dataset)` inside the `.then()`. Currently it is being logged before the promise is returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple issues here. 
First of all, as GTBebbo mentioned will be called before json gets data.
Second, your data is whole response object. So error will be thrown. You can use object destructuring to get data array from response

```js
let dataset;
const url =
  "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json";

d3.json(url)
// process response from json function
  .then(({ data }) => { // At thi moment we have response with json data
    return data.map(each => each[1]);
  })
  .then(dataArray => {
  // here you can manipulate with data
    console.log(dataArray);
  });
  
// This console calls earlier than json responce processed 
console.log("dataset", dataset);  // dataset = undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the console.log inside the promise.

You made the call to console.log right after calling the d3.json call, which returns immediately, but the promise happens afterwards.